# All my images are public to all android installed apps

Tags: android

I'm using this code to save images in the SD card (simulated or real) but all the testers of my app are telling me that the have a new folder in their Photos app with all my images (I don't know why on my Nexus 4 with KK this is not happening).

```
static public void storeImage(Bitmap image, String imgName) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myRoot = new File(root + "/files");
    if (!myRoot.exists()) {
        myRoot.mkdir();
    }
    File myDir = new File(root + "/images/");
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        myDir.mkdir();
    }
    File file = new File(BasePathToFile(imgName));
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change de visibility, security or something to avoid that the Photos App or any App get access to my folder??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A @Sebastian pointed getExternalFilesDir(String type) is a more complete solution so i have changed de code to this:

```
private static Boolean SdMemoryExist() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}

static public String BasePath(Context context) {
    String _basePathToCheck;
    if (SdMemoryExist()) {
        _basePathToCheck = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + File.separator;
    } else {
        _basePathToCheck = context.getFilesDir().toString() + File.separator;
    }
    return _basePathToCheck;
}

static public void storeImage(Bitmap image, String imgName, Context context) {

    File file = new File(BasePath(context), imgName);

    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.delete()) {
            createFile(image, file);
        }
    } else {
        createFile(image, file);
    }

}

static public void createFile(Bitmap image, File file) {
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot I have found [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) in the android dev page.

So at the end if you want that your files remain private you have to store them in the device.

So I have change my code to this:

```
static public void storeImage(Bitmap image, String imgName, Context context) {

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), imgName);

    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.delete()) {
            createFile(image, file);
        }
    } else {
        createFile(image, file);
    }

}

static public void createFile(Bitmap image, File file) {
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope this will be useful to someone.

Happy coding.

Comment: I think `getExternalFilesDir(String type)` is what you're looking for. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian your help took me to a better solution